# Environment VM arg passed to bootRun not being picked up by Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jvm

I am trying to set the environment of my Spring Boot (1.5.4.RELEASE) application at runtime, but it appears I have something out of alignment.

My application.yml is defined like this:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: ${env:local}
---
spring:
  profiles: local
  foo: bar
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  foo: bar
```

In a class that I have annotated as @Configuration, I have a method that does the following just so I can show the environment that is being used:

```
@Value('${spring.profiles.active}')
String activeProfile

@PostConstruct
def bootComplete() {
    println "App started with profile: $activeProfile"
}
```

Under this configuration, when my application starts, I see this in the console:

```
App started with profile: local
```

If I modify **${env:local}** to be **${env:dev}** in my application.yml and I start the application, I see this in the console:

```
App started with profile: dev
```

My goal is to start the application with VM arguments to set the active profile at runtime.  I am adding the argument:  **-Denv=dev** but it appears that it has no effect on the starting of the application.  Can anyone suggest what I might be overlooking here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem.  The issue was that I was starting the application using Gradle bootRun.  My assumption was that the VM args set there would be used.  I am now running the application by calling the class directly, and the VM args are working (both -Denv and -Dspring.profiles.active)

Answer (score 0):

Doing `-Denv=env` will not make any effect since `env` is not a property key.
This is how you can do it:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunatley, I started with  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev, and am still seeing the active profile as local.